# Substring elements in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For python DataFrame i need to select specific characters for each element in a column

```
df['y'] = df['x'].apply(lambda x: x[1:4])
```

but getting this error

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need [`indexing with str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) which handle `NaN` and `None`s too:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'x' : ['abcdef','av', 'a', None, np.nan]})
df['y'] = df['x'].str[1:4]
print (df)

        x     y
0  abcdef   bcd
1      av     v
2       a      
3    None  None
4     NaN   NaN
```

EDIT:

I suggest first indexing by `str[1:]`, then split by sparator and then `str[0]` for seelct first splitted lists:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'x' : ['abc|etf','av|ee', 'ayty|s', None, np.nan]})

df['y'] = df['x'].str[1:].str.split('|').str[0]
print (df)

         x     y
0  abc|etf    bc
1    av|ee     v
2   ayty|s   yty
3     None  None
4      NaN   NaN
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'x' : ['abc|Ttf','av|Re', 'ayty|s','ayty|','ayty', None, np.nan]})

def f(x):
    #find position
    pos = x.find('|')
    #if no match return same value
    if pos == -1:
        return x
    #else procees code - split
    else:
        return x[:pos+2]

mask = df['x'].notnull()
df.loc[mask, 'y'] = df.loc[mask, 'x'].apply(f)
print (df)

         x       y
0  abc|Ttf   abc|T
1    av|Re    av|R
2   ayty|s  ayty|s
3    ayty|   ayty|
4     ayty    ayty
5     None     NaN
6      NaN     NaN
```

Comment: @jezreal is `str[]` in practice same as `str.slice` like sugar syntax or are they different?

Comment: @RafaelC - hmmm, hard question for me. No idea, but I try find something relevant.

Comment: @RafaelC - maybe main difference is `[]` is more common, it seems like syntactic sugar. Also interesting is it is only pandas function (str.slice), in pure python not exist [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html)

Comment: Thanks jezreal and RafaelC
instead of indexing till 4 i was trying to index it to a specific character 
e.g: ind=df['x'].str.find("_") finds location of the character "_"

and then apply df['y'] = df['x'].str[1:ind] 

What is the right way to do it

Comment: thanks @jezreal for your help
i hate to add a complexity, the data needs to be sliced from index +1 (i.e. from abc|etf --> abc|e)

Answer (score 0):

Can also use [`str.slice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.str.slice.html)

```
>>> df.x.str.slice(1,4)
```

e.g.

```
df.x

0    abcdef
1    abcdef
2    abcdef
3      None
4    abcdef

df.a.str.slice(1,4)

0     bcd
1     bcd
2     bcd
3    None
4     bcd
```